# How reset the button keep the score in android

Tags: java, android

I try to create a simple quiz app and I need to have a Reset Button.So,when user clicks on Reset Button score should goes to  0.But something goes wrong with my code and can't figure it. 
        Thanks for any help!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String Name;
    int score = 0;
    int resetScore = 0;
    Button submitButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitAnswer);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submitButton.setText("Your score is:" + score);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayResult(int score) {
        TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        result.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    public void resetScore(View view){
        resetScore= 0;
        displayResetScore(resetScore);
    }

    private void displayResetScore(int resetScore) {
        TextView ResetButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);
        ResetButton.setText(String.valueOf(resetScore));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.allyouask.hungryforhistory.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:textColor="#EF6C00"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeMessage"
            style="@style/WelcomeScreenText"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Welcome to Hungry For History!\n         Let's get started!"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstQuestion"
            style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeMessage"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Who was born in Ancient City Stagira, Greece?"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/firstLeftCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/firstQuestion"
            android:text="Aristotle"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/firstRightCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/firstQuestion"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="Pythagoras"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondQuestion"
            style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/firstLeftCheckBox"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Who said in his last speech:With malice toward none;...let us strive on to finish the work we are in;to bind up the nation's wounds;into care for him who shall have borne the battle and for his widow and his orphans?"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondLeftCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/secondQuestion"
            android:text="William McKinley"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/secondRightCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/secondQuestion"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="Abraham Lincoln"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thirdQuestion"
            style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/secondLeftCheckBox"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Where the An Lushan Rebellion took place?"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/thirdLeftCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thirdQuestion"
            android:text="China"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/thirdRightCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thirdQuestion"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thirdLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="Thailand"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fourthQuestion"
            style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thirdLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="Who was the most famous exemplar of absolute monarchy in France?"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/fourthLeftCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fourthQuestion"
            android:text="Louis XIV"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/fourthRightCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fourthQuestion"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourthLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="Michael I"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fifthQuestion"
            style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fourthLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="When Alexander The Great lived?"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/fifthLeftCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fifthQuestion"
            android:text="330-323 BC"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/fifthRightCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fifthQuestion"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fifthLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="336-323 BC"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sixthQuestion"
            style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fifthLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="Where Albert Einstein studied?"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sixthLeftCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sixthQuestion"
            android:text="University of Zurich"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sixthRightCheckBox"
            style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sixthQuestion"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sixthLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="University of Germany"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seventhQuestion"
            style="@style/QuestionsStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sixthLeftCheckBox"
            android:text="What was the main interest of Democritus?"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioButtons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/seventhQuestion"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/astronomyRadioButton"
                style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mathematics-Astronomy"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/philosophyRadioButton"
                style="@style/CheckBoxStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Philosophy-Psychology"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitAnswer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioButtons"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:onClick="OnClickSubmit"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ResetButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/submitAnswer"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:onClick="OnClickReset"
            android:background="@color/backgroundResetColor"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `android:onClick="OnClickReset"` in xml should be `android:onClick="resetScore"` or your Java function should be called `OnClickReset()`. They just need to be the same name. Not sure where you got this syntax from.

Comment: `resetScore` is always 0, it doesn't make sense to create a variable that will never change its value.

Comment: Hi codeMagic,I did what you suggest but app crashes when reset button is clicked. I ll post my log to see:

Comment: Hi Juan,I didn't understand you very well, if I just delete the value of resetScore nothing change, app crashes again when resetButton is clicked,what I ll should do to make reset button work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the 'score' variable when adding score during the game, you have to set score to 0 when pressing the button, not 'resetScore'.

```
public void resetScore(View view){
    score = 0;
    displayResetScore(score);
}

 private void displayResetScore(int resetScore) {
    ResetButton.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}
```

Reading your error log, you could also try to declare the textview like this instead:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitAnswer);
    TextView ResetButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ResetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity.onCreate() method you added an OnClicklistener for submitButton. Do the same for resetButton. And please rename that button to lower case 'resetButton'.

Comment: this is `camelCase` not lowercase: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles

Comment: Hi botzek, what you said sounds good, but  when I ll create the resetButton in the main how can I put the score from "submitAnswer" button to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, resetButton works. Here is my code from MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String Name;
    int score = 0;
    Button submitButton;
    Button resetButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         EditText nameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameField);
         String name = nameField.getText().toString();

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submitButton.setText("Your score is:" + score);
                //submitButton.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            }
        });
        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submitButton.setText((String.valueOf(0)));
            }
        });
    }
```